# UIWebView HTML 5 game Canvas drawing slowness in iOS 9, or WebGL crashing in iOS 8.0 and above

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, webgl

I've having an issue with UIWebView and running HTML 5 games (that another developer is working on). We've tried two different options, and neither is optimal.

Option 1: He renders the HTML 5 game with "canvas drawing". When he does it this way, nothing crashes, however in iOS 9 when we go back into the app from the background, the Web View loads back up, but the game is moving much slower than normal (issue not on iOS 7.1 and above). By much slower I'm talking about the animations are not moving the same velocity that they were when we first load the game. The weird thing about this issue is that even if the user opens up a different HTML 5 game (we're adding multiple games) the animations are slower for that game as well. I've tried dismissing the Web View Controller when the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification gets posted. When I set the game up this way, the slowness only happens if the app is in the for 4 seconds (it's very strange).

Option 2: He renders the game with "WebGL". When he renders it this way, the app crashes when the app gets backgrounded on iOS 8.0 and above. My research into the crash is that iOS can't draw OpenGL ES in the background. I'm assuming that the WebGL commands are running similar commands as OpenGL ES would do, hence the crash. Dismissing the Web View Controller on UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification still causes the crash to happen.

Has anyone else ever dealt with a situation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not found a good solution to the problem, but I did find a work around.

When I get the App Will Resign Active message, I remove the UIWebView from the UIWebViewController's subview. When I get the Did Become Active message, I add the UIWebView to the UIWebViewController's subview.

This solution works for both cases.

Comment: From this you could have triggered JavaScript events that stop & restart the animation so this does not happen when using the OpenGL ES method

Comment: One of the solutions that we tried was to pause the game (by calling a JavaScript function on the web view). The function would bring up a pause screen. When we tried this solution the same problems were happening.

Comment: Yeah if you bring up a pause screen you could still have the draw loop running just drawing a pause screen. What i was trying to say was to build your draw loop using `setTimeout();` then you can put a pause method that calls `clearTimeout();` and your resume just calls your draw method that at the end of it uses `setTimeout` however without testing it's all theory based on my experience. :) i'm not saying to use this but i have an implementation of a Draw call in 2D using deltaTime and timeout based managment http://650h.rs/1R1f1uv